# Multiple Users Login in Same tab - Choose user screen - Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is it possible to create a custom authenticator where multiple users can login and we give option to change user without logging out the other user. kinda like google account chooser.
https://admin.google.com/ac/accountchooser?pli=1

As browser flow works on keycloak cookies(AUTH_COOKIE_ID, KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY, KEYCLOAK_SESSION). I believe we will to use these cookies. Is there any way we can customize these cookies.
Any insight on how can we achieve this using custom authenticator or anything that will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: In case you use just one or two cookies, and are using https:// , can't you embed the unique references in the GET/POST requests? That way,  you are compliant with all browsers, irrespective of how they handle the realm, and it will work across tabs